# WordPress - Making extra parameters optional

Tags: wordpress, parameters, option-type

I am trying to get page parameters without editing `.htaccess` in WordPress
like this:

From:http://localhost/wordpress1/download/?image=64&resolution=1024x768&nonce=a102d152a0

to:
http://localhost/wordpress1/download/64/1024x768/a102d152a0/

My code is below, it is not working and results in a 404 error.

```
function new_rewrite_rule(){
    add_rewrite_rule(
        'download/([0-9]+)/([a-z]+)/([a-z]+)/?$',
        'index.php?pagename=download&image=$matches[1]&resolution=$matches[2]&nonce=$matches[3]',
        'top'
    );
}
add_action( 'init', 'new_rewrite_rule' );

function new_query_vars( $query_vars ) {
    $query_vars[] = 'image';
    $query_vars[] = 'resolution';
    $query_vars[] = 'nonce';

    return $query_vars;
}
add_filter( 'query_vars', 'new_query_vars' );
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

solved by me ,
Final Code

```
    function new_rewrite_rule(){
    global $wp_rewrite; 
    $wp_rewrite->flush_rules(); 

    add_rewrite_rule(
        'download/([0-9]+)/([a-zA-z0-9]+)/([a-zA-z0-9]+)/?$',
        'index.php?pagename=download&image=$matches[1]&resolution=$matches[2]&nonce=$matches[3]',
        'top'
    );
}

add_action( 'init', 'new_rewrite_rule' );

function new_query_vars( $query_vars ) {
    $query_vars[] = 'image';
    $query_vars[] = 'resolution';
    $query_vars[] = 'nonce';

    return $query_vars;
}
add_filter( 'query_vars', 'new_query_vars' );
```